# Code to cut and paste from within a For Next Loop. How can I specifically do this using a For Each loop instead?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

I would like to use a For Each loop to cut and paste an entire row from one worksheet to another, given that a condition is met.

Here I do that within a For/Next Loop, but I understand that those loops are much slower than using a For/Each Loop which is my preference. I need to know how to do the cut-and-paste (in explicit terms) within a For/Each Loop within the sub "Process" below.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
Dim wbm, wbr As Workbook, wsm, wsr, wsc As Worksheet, LastRowC, LastRowr As Integer, Match As Boolean, ColV, v As Range, vaddr As String

Option Explicit

Public Sub Initialize()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlManual: Application.EnableEvents = False

'Must have the correct worksheet name below:

Set wbr = Workbooks("LST_102019_25590000-25590200_MULTIPLE_ACCRUAL ROLL FORWARD TEMPLATE V1.0.xlsm")
Set wsr = wbr.Sheets("Open Items")
Set wsc = wbr.Sheets("Closed Items")

LastRowr = wsr.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sort_WBSe

Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Public Sub Sort_WBSe()

    wsr.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wsr.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("V7"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With wsr.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Process

End Sub


Public Sub Process()

Dim N As Integer, Amt, AmtNext, WBSe, WBSeNext As String
LastRowC = wsc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Dim i As Long: i = LastRowC + 1 'Set the next row of the Closed Items sheet

'Col V is the WBSe column

'Note: This loop works from the bottom up.


With wsr

    For N = LastRowr To 7 Step -1

        WBSe = .Cells(N, "V"): Amt = .Cells(N, "V").Offset(0, -3)
        WBSeNext = .Cells(N, "V").Offset(-1, 0): AmtNext = .Cells(N, "V").Offset(-1, -3) * -1

        If WBSeNext = WBSe And (AmtNext) = Amt Then
            .Cells(N, "V").EntireRow.Cut wsc.Cells(i, "A") 'Cut the Row and Paste it to the Closed Items sheet
             If .Cells(N, "V") = "" Then
                .Cells(N, "V").EntireRow.Delete 'Delete the Blank Row
             End If

             i = i + 1

            .Cells(N - 1, "V").EntireRow.Cut wsc.Cells(i, "A") 'Cut the Row and Paste it to the Closed Items sheet
             If .Cells(N - 1, "V") = "" Then
                .Cells(N - 1, "V").EntireRow.Delete 'Delete the Blank Row
             End If
             i = i + 1
             N = N - 1
       End If

    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: If your code works and you just want to optimize it, then this question may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Set your range from V7 to V and last row, then loop through each cell in the range, Also, use offset as needed

Comment: If optimization is your goal, there are larger things to improve than the loop type. ```EntireRow.Delete``` is slowing things down far more than the loop is.

Comment: Thanks for responses.

Comment: Thanks for all responses and will consider all of them.  GMalc:  Performance is extremely slow and borderline unstable.  Also, I had tried a For/Each Loop down Column V using offsets, but I couldn't get the correct syntax for the copy & paste.  That is why I posted this question in hope of getting the correct syntax for the copy and paste within the context of a For Each loop. Mathieu G:  Will change variables mentioned to Long, but from my experience "Dim wbm, wbr as Workbook declares both as workbooks or I would have seen many errors on this and other code I have written.

Comment: Mathieu G:  I see you are correct about dimming multiple variables and I have been doing it the wrong way.  It wouldn't result in an "Object not defined" error either, so it worked but was wrong.  Thanks for pointing that out.